# Как прижать элементы к краям родителя вертикально на flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.projects-wrapper{
     min-width: 250px;
     max-width: 250px;
     min-height: 250px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     background: grey;
}
.project-item{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="colum projects-wrapper">
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_f_students_of_kpi.png)"></div>
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_clubs_nagoruny.png)"></div>
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/r_complex_campus.png)"></div>
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_f_students_of_kpi2.png)"></div>
</div>
```

Здравствуйте, у flex-box есть чудесное свойство `justify-content: space-between;`, которое прижимает элементы к краям горизонтально. Есть ли что-то подобное, когда надо прижать вертикально? или есть другой способ не *flex-box*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
align-content: space-between;
```

```css
.projects-wrapper{
     min-width: 250px;
     max-width: 250px;
     min-height: 250px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     background: grey;    
     align-content: space-between;
}
.project-item{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="colum projects-wrapper">
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_f_students_of_kpi.png)"></div>
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_clubs_nagoruny.png)"></div>
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/r_complex_campus.png)"></div>
    <div class="project-item" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_f_students_of_kpi2.png)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте что вы хотите построить , row  или column:

```
  flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
```

Или если у вас row , и надо прижать  верху то :

```
align-items: start;
```

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Нет, во флексбоксе так нельзя, потому что у него есть всего одна ось, а вы хотите сделать двумерную раскладку. Для этого используется сетка (CSS Grid Layout).

Разверните на весь экран, сможете увидеть как эта раскладка работает на любом разрешении.

```css
.projects-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  background: grey;
}

.project-item {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.project-item--1,
.project-item--2 {
  align-self: start;
}

.project-item--3,
.project-item--4 {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="colum projects-wrapper">
  <div class="project-item project-item--1" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_f_students_of_kpi.png)"></div>
  <div class="project-item project-item--2" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_clubs_nagoruny.png)"></div>
  <div class="project-item project-item--3" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/r_complex_campus.png)"></div>
  <div class="project-item project-item--4" style="background-image: url(css/img/projects/h_f_students_of_kpi2.png)"></div>
</div>
```

Что касается не-флексбокс решения: если имелось в виду, что это надо сделать каким-нибудь древним способом, то к ваши услугам абсолютное позиционирование :-)